# cURL - not properly working with JSON requests or Not saving Session

Tags: php, json, session, redirect, curl

everyone!

I have 2 Controllers that are meant to search for something on some websites. you can search on them only if you are logged in. So.. I was tracking the POST Request and the data goes to a file that give an answer and then the login page redirects to the normal logged in page.

First Controller Code

```
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, self::loginUrl);
        #curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$httpHeader);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

        curl_exec($ch);
```

So, it goes to loginUrl, post the data and displays 1, instead of the website(with me logged in). 1 is the answer that the JSON file give for successful login. My problem is that I am not logged in, even if I set a new curl handler to the home url. The same problem goes for the second Controller, with the code:

```
$ch = curl_init(self::loginUrl);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie_'.self::site.'.txt');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE , 'cookie_'.self::site.'.txt');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, self::refUrl);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $requestHeaders);
            #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);
```

Sorry if I used bad indenting or bad english. Have a nice day!

EDIT: It May come from bad cookie using, because my cookie file is empty, any advice on this, how could I test it?